# Deprecation Warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, xgboost

```
import operator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xgboost as xgb
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
```

After importing the above files I got a module not found error because I didn't had xboost installed since i'm new to python and data analysis.

Then I installed it directly from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost).

Now after installing xgboost i'm getting a deprecation warning for the same above lines of code which is as follows :

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: 
DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor
of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and
functions are moved.
Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from
that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
```

Please tell me why this warning is showing up and how to resolve this?

Comment: It means that in later versions of the product the code you are using will no longer work. Read the docs of the `model_selection` module and fit your code into that so that users will be able to use your code with later versions.

Comment: Sklearn will be sunsetting cross_validation. They put the classes that were under cross_validation into now model_selection. I think XGBoost also has updated because they are using `try`/ `except` for importing `KFold`, `StratifiedKFold` (for [example](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/6f16f0ef5829965ba420ef6937617600d286820a/python-package/xgboost/compat.py#L51)).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

Instead

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
```

Comment: There is no such line of code in the OP's question, so what are you even answering?

Comment: @Ajean I just have the same error: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor
of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and
functions are moved. ...... So probably he is import the cross_validation in other files or at line 44 (that's what the deprecation warning say).

Comment: That's just a guess.  Instead of writing an answer you should ask the OP in a comment.  You can't do that yet, but you should wait until you can, otherwise your answer could very well be wrong and hence attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This will suppress all DeprecationWarnings.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

If you want to learn more, you can read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html).